# Eclipse ARM debugging view

Tags: eclipse, debugging, gdb, arm, ds-5

Is there any kind of plugins for eclipse that will show Stack Pointer, Call stack, Watch (for variable) and sth else that will help us debugging code via eclipse?

Comment: [Yes](http://ds.arm.com/ds-5-community-edition/).

Comment: So could you tell me the name of it or insert some links? 
Stack pointer and call stack will be very helpful :)

Comment: Um, that _is_ a link to the only one I know of. I guess trying to retain an air of objectivity in an off-topic recommendation question is hard ;)

Comment: Oh you're right :) I accidently dismiss it in your previous answer :)
Than you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use ARM DS-5, which comes with a compiler, debugger and performance analyzer. Visit http://ds.arm.com for more details.